# Make routes case insensitive in angular 5

Tags: angular5

I have implemented the following code:

```
import { DefaultUrlSerializer, UrlTree, UrlSerializer  } from '@angular/router';
export class LowerCaseUrlSerializer extends DefaultUrlSerializer {
  parse(url: string): UrlTree {
    const urlParts = url.split('?');
    urlParts[0] = urlParts[0].toLowerCase(); 
    return super.parse(urlParts.join('?')); 
  }
}
export const LowerCaseUrlSerializerProvider = {
  provide: UrlSerializer,
  useClass: LowerCaseUrlSerializer
};
```

Witch I regisiter in app.module.ts

```
 providers: [
    LowerCaseUrlSerializerProvider,
```

And if I write in the route manually (/signIn) it works just fine. But if I use routelink like this:

```
<a routerLink="/signIn" routerLinkActive="active">
```

I get an error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'signIn'

What am I doing wrong?

edit: the following works

```
<a routerLink="/signin" routerLinkActive="active">
```